How to fade SVG objects on mouse hover
I am having trouble getting SVG and CSS to play together to get the function I want.  I want to be able to hover over the pie sectors of a graph and have the info in the middle change.  I want the sector that is hovered over to remain and all other sectors to dim.  Also, I don't want any dimming to happen if you hover over the center circle.  This is what I've come up with so far which is close.  The text in the middle I'm having trouble with because it is layered (if filter: opacity(50%) is changed to 0% then the text behaves but all the other sectors vanish instead of dim).  Any suggestions on how to make this behave?


* {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  /* Top  Right  Bottom  Left */
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  /* Top  Right  Bottom  Left */
  border: 0px solid #00FF00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #002233;
  color: #FFC355;
  font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/* fade transitions on hover - DIV, SVG, TEXT */

#parent>div,
path,
text {
  transition: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 5ms;
}


/* fade ALL out on parent hover - SVG (Sector Groups) */

#parent1:hover>g {
  filter: opacity(50%) blur(0px) brightness(80%);
}


/* fade ONE in on hover - SVG (Sector Groups) */

#parent1>g:hover {
  filter: opacity(100%) blur(0px) brightness(100%);
}

#parent2:hover>g {
  filter: opacity(0%) blur(0px) brightness(80%);
}


/* fade ONE in on hover - SVG (Sector Groups) */

#parent2>g:hover {
  filter: opacity(100%) blur(0px) brightness(100%);
}
<div>
  <svg width='500px' height='500px' viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='240' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0' fill-opacity='1' />
    <g id='parent1' stroke-width='2.5' stroke-linecap='butt' stroke-linejoin='miter' stroke='black'>
      <g id='parent1'>
        <path d='M 250 250 L 250 25 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 458.7056796681 334.06508950971 Z'
          fill='#d35400' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>8.21 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>31.1%</text>
      </g>
      <g id='parent1'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 458.7056796681 334.06508950971 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 171.59428106039 460.89699674856 Z'
          fill='#aa2200' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>6.49 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>24.6%</text>
      </g>
      <g id='parent1'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 171.59428106039 460.89699674856 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 56.284491015906 364.45218031577 Z'
          fill='#eb2f06' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>2.86 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>10.8%</text>
      </g>
      <g id='parent1'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 56.284491015906 364.45218031577 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 26.24340850501 226.37823540579 Z'
          fill='#c23616' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>2.68 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>10.2%</text>
      </g>
      <g id='parent1'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 26.24340850501 226.37823540579 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 71.089441212269 113.55949298591 Z'
          fill='#e67e22' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>2.30 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>8.70%</text>
      </g>
      <g id='parent1'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 71.089441212269 113.55949298591 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 163.8235888855 42.15720804554 Z'
          fill='#ffc500' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>2.21 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>8.38%</text>
      </g>
      <g id='parent1'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 163.8235888855 42.15720804554 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 249.97751533812 25.000001123467 Z'
          fill='#f39c12' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>1.65 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>6.25%</text>
      </g>
      <g id='parent1'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 249.97751533812 25.000001123467 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 250.01678524623 25.000000626099 Z'
          fill='#425a62' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>0.42 H/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>0.00%</text>
      </g>
      <g id='parent1'>
        <path d='M 250 250 L 250.01678524623 25.000000626099 A 225 225, 0, , 1,  Z' fill='' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'></text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'></text>
      </g>
      <g>
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>26.41 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>$99.58 USD</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<div>
  <svg width='500px' height='500px' viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='240' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0' fill-opacity='1' />
    <g id='parent2' stroke-width='2.5' stroke-linecap='butt' stroke-linejoin='miter' stroke='black'>
      <g id='parent2'>
        <path d='M 250 250 L 250 25 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 458.7056796681 334.06508950971 Z'
          fill='#d35400' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>8.21 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>31.1%</text>
      </g>
      <g id='parent2'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 458.7056796681 334.06508950971 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 171.59428106039 460.89699674856 Z'
          fill='#aa2200' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>6.49 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>24.6%</text>
      </g>
      <g id='parent2'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 171.59428106039 460.89699674856 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 56.284491015906 364.45218031577 Z'
          fill='#eb2f06' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>2.86 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>10.8%</text>
      </g>
      <g id='parent2'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 56.284491015906 364.45218031577 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 26.24340850501 226.37823540579 Z'
          fill='#c23616' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>2.68 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>10.2%</text>
      </g>
      <g id='parent2'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 26.24340850501 226.37823540579 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 71.089441212269 113.55949298591 Z'
          fill='#e67e22' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>2.30 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>8.70%</text>
      </g>
      <g id='parent2'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 71.089441212269 113.55949298591 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 163.8235888855 42.15720804554 Z'
          fill='#ffc500' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>2.21 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>8.38%</text>
      </g>
      <g id='parent2'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 163.8235888855 42.15720804554 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 249.97751533812 25.000001123467 Z'
          fill='#f39c12' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>1.65 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>6.25%</text>
      </g>
      <g id='parent2'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 249.97751533812 25.000001123467 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 250.01678524623 25.000000626099 Z'
          fill='#425a62' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>0.42 H/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>0.00%</text>
      </g>
      <g id='parent2'>
        <path d='M 250 250 L 250.01678524623 25.000000626099 A 225 225, 0, , 1,  Z' fill='' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'></text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'></text>
      </g>
      <g>
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>26.41 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>$99.58 USD</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>



EDIT:  I have modified the code to show 2 versions of the graph... my goal is to have a hybrid of the two.  I want the center text to change when sectors are hovered over (like bottom graph), but only the sectors to dim and not disappear (like top graph - without the messy transparent text).  Also, I don't want the center to cause any diming and to just behave as if the mouse is not over the SVG at all.

A note on SVG inside HTML5: when used as a normal HTML element, SVG is not XML, and does not use namespaces: it should not include the xmlns attribute. Also note that width and heigh indicate the on-page size of the element, and so they need a unit, not just a number. And finally, you almost always want an explicit viewBox attribute (which is based on internal SVG units already, so uses plain numbers). And then on a plain HTML note: id attributes are meant to be unique identifiers. If that's not what you need, use class, not id.

(and of course: when used as element in HTML, just style things with CSS, rather than using the XML styling attributes. Saves a lot of text, so your document is smaller, and it makes your code much easier to both read and maintain)

This SVG pasted here is static, but the real one is built with PHP on the fly so the styling attributes are inline so that they can be changed by the PHP on creation.

Even then, making PHP not do that and instead making it generate a <style> element for the SVG element by giving the actual <svg> element an id and generating the styles tied to that id selector is probably worth it. That way you still get the power to change things at generation, while also getting better source code out of it.

Another side note, IDs must be unique

You probably got it all figured out with all the answers, but I have two points. First of all, you can use both the next-sibling combinator and the subsequent-sibling combinator to show/hide the text elements. Second, I like "constructing" SVGs, so I replaced your path elements with circle elements. If you have the data it is easy to calculate the length and rotation of the circle slices. Only drawback is that you need to mask off the spaces between the slices (here, just some line elements that are rotated).
Update
I misunderstood the dim/no dim requirement, so here is an update. It concerns the following two selectors that both use the :has() pseudo-class. If the .background has a subsequent sibling .slice that is hovered, all subsequent siblings should dim. A more specific selector says, that if the subsequent sibling is hovered is should stay bright.
.background:has(~.slice:hover)~.slice {
  filter: brightness(80%);
}

.background:has(~.slice:hover)~.slice:hover {
  filter: brightness(100%);
}



* {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  /* Top  Right  Bottom  Left */
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  /* Top  Right  Bottom  Left */
  border: 0px solid #00FF00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #002233;
  color: #FFC355;
  font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.slice {
  filter: brightness(100%);
}

.background:has(~.slice:hover)~.slice {
  filter: brightness(80%);
}

.background:has(~.slice:hover)~.slice:hover {
  filter: brightness(100%);
}

.slice+g {
  filter: opacity(0%);
}

.slice:hover+g {
  filter: opacity(100%);
}

.slice:hover~g.total {
  filter: opacity(0%);
}
<svg height="100vh" viewBox="0 0 500 500" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold"
  text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" font-size="40" fill="white">
  <g transform="translate(250 250)">
    <circle class="background" r="250" fill="black" />
    <circle class="slice" r="190" transform="rotate(-90)" fill="none" stroke="#d35400"
      stroke-width="100" stroke-dasharray="311 1000" pathLength="1000" />
    <g>
      <text>8.21 KH/s</text>
      <text dy="40" font-size="20" fill="#444444">31.1%</text>
    </g>
    <circle class="slice" r="190" transform="rotate(-90)" fill="none" stroke="#aa2200"
      stroke-width="100" stroke-dasharray="246 1000" stroke-dashoffset="-311" pathLength="1000" />
    <g>
      <text>6.49 KH/s</text>
      <text dy="40" font-size="20" fill="#444444">24.6%</text>
    </g>
    <circle class="slice" r="190" transform="rotate(-90)" fill="none" stroke="#eb2f06"
      stroke-width="100" stroke-dasharray="108 1000" stroke-dashoffset="-557" pathLength="1000" />
    <g>
      <text>2.86 KH/s</text>
      <text dy="40" font-size="20" fill="#444444">10.8%</text>
    </g>
    <circle class="slice" r="190" transform="rotate(-90)" fill="none" stroke="#c23616"
      stroke-width="100" stroke-dasharray="102 1000" stroke-dashoffset="-665" pathLength="1000" />
    <g>
      <text>2.68 KH/s</text>
      <text dy="40" font-size="20" fill="#444444">10.2%</text>
    </g>
    <circle class="slice" r="190" transform="rotate(-90)" fill="none" stroke="#e67e22"
      stroke-width="100" stroke-dasharray="87 1000" stroke-dashoffset="-767" pathLength="1000" />
    <g>
      <text>2.30 KH/s</text>
      <text dy="40" font-size="20" fill="#444444">8.70%</text>
    </g>
    <circle class="slice" r="190" transform="rotate(-90)" fill="none" stroke="#ffc500"
      stroke-width="100" stroke-dasharray="83.8 1000" stroke-dashoffset="-854" pathLength="1000" />
    <g>
      <text>2.21 KH/s</text>
      <text dy="40" font-size="20" fill="#444444">8.38%</text>
    </g>
    <circle class="slice" r="190" transform="rotate(-90)" fill="none" stroke="#f39c12"
      stroke-width="100" stroke-dasharray="62.5 1000" stroke-dashoffset="-937.8" pathLength="1000" />
    <g>
      <text>1.65 KH/s</text>
      <text dy="40" font-size="20" fill="#444444">6.25%</text>
    </g>
    <g stroke="black" stroke-width="4" pointer-events="none">
      <line y1="-140" y2="-240" />
      <line y1="-140" y2="-240" transform="rotate(112)" />
      <line y1="-140" y2="-240" transform="rotate(200.5)" />
      <line y1="-140" y2="-240" transform="rotate(239.4)" />
      <line y1="-140" y2="-240" transform="rotate(276)" />
      <line y1="-140" y2="-240" transform="rotate(307.4)" />
      <line y1="-140" y2="-240" transform="rotate(337.6)" />
    </g>
    <g class="total">
      <text>26.41 KH/s</text>
      <text dy="40" font-size="20" fill="#444444">$99.58 USD</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>




Wow, using stroke-dasharray to make donut chart is really creative. Much less calculation and path shenanigans too. Very nice hack :)

If I understand your solution, you dim everything and brighten the sectors as they are hovered.  However, this makes them always dim unless you hover over them.  My intent is to have them all bright until you hover which dims all other sectors.  I'm investigating if I can do this with your solution.

BTW, I love the stroke-dasharray hack.  I eliminates the need to mask the center at all.  I'll be using this a lot going forward.  Thank you for this tip alone!!

@DavidHeadrick I updated my answer.

Excellent.  This is perfect and very clever.  Thanks.  It took me a bit to digest your solution because I don't use CSS everyday.

Use clipPath to trim the inner part of each sector, then adjust the conditions like this:


* {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  /* Top  Right  Bottom  Left */
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  /* Top  Right  Bottom  Left */
  border: 0px solid #00FF00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #002233;
  color: #FFC355;
  font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/* fade transitions on hover - DIV, SVG, TEXT */

#parent>div,
path,
text {
  transition: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 5ms;
}


/* fade ALL out on hover (but not when .center is hovered) */

#donut-chart:hover:not(:has(.center:hover)) .parent>path {
  filter: opacity(50%) blur(0px) brightness(80%);
}


/* Also hide all text */

#donut-chart:hover:not(:has(.center:hover)) .parent>:is(circle, text) {
  filter: opacity(0%);
}


/* fade ONE in on hover*/

#donut-chart:hover:not(:has(.center:hover)) .parent>path:hover {
  filter: none;
}


/* Hide the .center... */

#donut-chart:hover:not(:has(.center:hover)) .center {
  filter: opacity(0%);
}


/* ...and show the hovered sector's text */

#donut-chart:hover:not(:has(.center:hover)) .parent:has(path:hover)>:is(circle, text) {
  filter: none;
}
<div>
  <svg width='500px' height='500px' viewBox="0 0 500 500">
            <clipPath id="myClip">
                <path
                    d="M 10, 250 a 240,240 0 1,0 480,0 a 240,240 0 1,0 -480,0 M 126.25, 250 a 123.75,123.75 0 1,0 247.5,0 a 123.75,123.75 0 1,0 -247.5,0"
                    clip-rule="evenodd" />
            </clipPath>
            <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='240' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0' fill-opacity='1' />
            <g id="donut-chart" stroke-width='2.5' stroke-linecap='butt' stroke-linejoin='miter' stroke='black'>
                <g class='parent'>
                    <path d='M 250 250 L 250 25 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 458.7056796681 334.06508950971 Z' fill='#d35400'
                        clip-path='url(#myClip)' />
                    <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
                        fill-opacity='1' />
                    <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
                        dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>8.21 KH/s</text>
                    <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
                        dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>31.1%</text>
                </g>
                <g class='parent'>
                    <path
                        d='M 250 250 L 458.7056796681 334.06508950971 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 171.59428106039 460.89699674856 Z'
                        fill='#aa2200' clip-path='url(#myClip)' />
                    <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
                        fill-opacity='1' />
                    <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
                        dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>6.49 KH/s</text>
                    <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
                        dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>24.6%</text>
                </g>
                <g class='parent'>
                    <path
                        d='M 250 250 L 171.59428106039 460.89699674856 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 56.284491015906 364.45218031577 Z'
                        fill='#eb2f06' clip-path='url(#myClip)' />
                    <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
                        fill-opacity='1' />
                    <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
                        dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>2.86 KH/s</text>
                    <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
                        dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>10.8%</text>
                </g>
                <g class='parent'>
                    <path
                        d='M 250 250 L 56.284491015906 364.45218031577 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 26.24340850501 226.37823540579 Z'
                        fill='#c23616' clip-path='url(#myClip)' />
                    <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
                        fill-opacity='1' />
                    <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
                        dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>2.68 KH/s</text>
                    <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
                        dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>10.2%</text>
                </g>
                <g class='parent'>
                    <path
                        d='M 250 250 L 26.24340850501 226.37823540579 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 71.089441212269 113.55949298591 Z'
                        fill='#e67e22' clip-path='url(#myClip)' />
                    <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
                        fill-opacity='1' />
                    <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
                        dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>2.30 KH/s</text>
                    <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
                        dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>8.70%</text>
                </g>
                <g class='parent'>
                    <path
                        d='M 250 250 L 71.089441212269 113.55949298591 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 163.8235888855 42.15720804554 Z'
                        fill='#ffc500' clip-path='url(#myClip)' />
                    <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
                        fill-opacity='1' />
                    <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
                        dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>2.21 KH/s</text>
                    <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
                        dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>8.38%</text>
                </g>
                <g class='parent'>
                    <path
                        d='M 250 250 L 163.8235888855 42.15720804554 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 249.97751533812 25.000001123467 Z'
                        fill='#f39c12' clip-path='url(#myClip)' />
                    <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
                        fill-opacity='1' />
                    <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
                        dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>1.65 KH/s</text>
                    <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
                        dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>6.25%</text>
                </g>
                <g class="center">
                    <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
                        fill-opacity='1' />
                    <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
                        dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>26.41 KH/s</text>
                    <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
                        dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>$99.58 USD</text>
                </g>
            </g>
        </svg>
</div>




I will check it out... this seems to behave exactly the way I wanted.  Thank you!  I will mark it answered after taking a closer look.

@DavidHeadrick Actually, I think you should consider chrwahl's answer. Even if the hover logic is not exactly as you want, his SVG elements are much more simple, elegant, and easy to maintain. Which also make implementing you desired hover logic much easier too.

I will look at chrwahl's solutions also.  They both function how I want so they both are good.  Simple is always better.

Ah, you are so close.
since everything is named "parent" it gets difficult to exclude the center part. so, what i did is name the individual sectors only as "parent". The mid part is not named anything, because we don't want to change anything there.
And then have two styles in css - one which says that if a "parent" element is hovered over, keep its opacity, brightness at 100% (you could just not have a style and it should still work, i guess).
The other style is to tell that the mouse is hovered over the svg-container div, but is not hovered over a "parent" element, the lower the opacity and brightness.


* {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  /* Top  Right  Bottom  Left */
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  /* Top  Right  Bottom  Left */
  border: 0px solid #00FF00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #002233;
  color: #FFC355;
  font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* fade transitions on hover - DIV, SVG, TEXT */

#parent>div,
path,
text {
  transition: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 5ms;
}


/* fade ALL out on parent hover - SVG (Sector Groups) */

.parent:hover {
  filter: opacity(100%) blur(0px) brightness(100%);
}

.svg-container:hover .parent:not(:hover) {
  filter: opacity(50%) blur(0px) brightness(80%);
}
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg width='500px' height='500px' viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='240' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0' fill-opacity='1' />
    <g stroke-width='2.5' stroke-linecap='butt' stroke-linejoin='miter' stroke='black'>
      <g class='parent'>
        <path d='M 250 250 L 250 25 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 458.7056796681 334.06508950971 Z'
          fill='#d35400' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>8.21 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>31.1%</text>
      </g>
      <g class='parent'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 458.7056796681 334.06508950971 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 171.59428106039 460.89699674856 Z'
          fill='#aa2200' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>6.49 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>24.6%</text>
      </g>
      <g class='parent'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 171.59428106039 460.89699674856 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 56.284491015906 364.45218031577 Z'
          fill='#eb2f06' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>2.86 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>10.8%</text>
      </g>
      <g class='parent'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 56.284491015906 364.45218031577 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 26.24340850501 226.37823540579 Z'
          fill='#c23616' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>2.68 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>10.2%</text>
      </g>
      <g class='parent'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 26.24340850501 226.37823540579 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 71.089441212269 113.55949298591 Z'
          fill='#e67e22' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>2.30 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>8.70%</text>
      </g>
      <g class='parent'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 71.089441212269 113.55949298591 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 163.8235888855 42.15720804554 Z'
          fill='#ffc500' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>2.21 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>8.38%</text>
      </g>
      <g class='parent'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 163.8235888855 42.15720804554 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 249.97751533812 25.000001123467 Z'
          fill='#f39c12' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>1.65 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>6.25%</text>
      </g>
      <g class='parent'>
        <path
          d='M 250 250 L 249.97751533812 25.000001123467 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 250.01678524623 25.000000626099 Z'
          fill='#425a62' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>0.42 H/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>0.00%</text>
      </g>
      <g class='parent'>
        <path d='M 250 250 L 250.01678524623 25.000000626099 A 225 225, 0, , 1,  Z' fill='' />
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'></text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'></text>
      </g>
      <g>
        <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='123.75' stroke='black' fill='black' stroke-width='0'
          fill-opacity='1' />
        <text x='250' y='240' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='40px' stroke-width='0' fill='#DDDDDD'>26.41 KH/s</text>
        <text x='250' y='280' font-family='Arial' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'
          dominant-baseline='middle' font-size='20px' stroke-width='0' fill='#444444'>$99.58 USD</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>



Of course, the downside of this is that the sectors turn dull as soon as you are over the svg-container div.

Yes, I would like the center to change text but not cause any dulling of the sectors when hovered over.  I only want dulling when a sector is hovered over.

May be you can add the hover effect on the svg element itself, instead of the svg-container. That would mean that it will made dull only when we go over the svg.

SVG is much like HTML in the way of styling with CSS (there are some differences syntactically and some legacy code). The following is the relevant CSS that will enable the behavior you requested.
.primary {
  fill-opacity: 0.4;
  transition: 0.75s ease-in-out;
}

.primary:not(:hover) {
 fill-opacity: 1.0
}

.section:hover {
 fill-opacity: 1.0;
 transition: 0.75s ease-in-out;
}

.section:hover~.center {
  fill-opacity: 1.0
}

I also cleaned up the extra garbage that was copied and pasted and fixed 2 of the broken <text> groups. To fix the rest of them you need to assign proper x and y coordinates. Also there should be only 2 <circle>s the rest have been removed. Moreover ids are unique (only one #parent!) so be careful when you copy HTML.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

:root {
  font: 16px/1 "Segoe UI"
}

body {
  color: #FFC355;
  background-color: #002233;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.primary {
  fill-opacity: 0.4;
  transition: 0.75s ease-in-out;
}

.primary:not(:hover) {
  fill-opacity: 1.0
}

.section:hover {
  fill-opacity: 1.0;
  transition: 0.75s ease-in-out;
}

.section:hover~.center {
  fill-opacity: 1.0
}

text {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-anchor: middle;
  stroke-width: 0;
}

.khs {
  baseline-shift: -30;
}

.prc {
  baseline-shift: -55;
}
<main>
  <svg width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

  <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="240" stroke="black" fill="black" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="1" />

  <g class="primary" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke="black">

   <g class="section">
    <path id="p1" d="M 250 250 L 250 25 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 458.7056796681 334.06508950971 Z" fill="#d35400" />
    <text class="khs" x="250" y="240" font-size="30px" fill="#DDD">
     <textpath xlink:href="#p1" startOffset="25%">8.21 KH/s</textpath>
    </text>
    <text class="prc" x="250" y="280" font-size="15px" fill="#444">
     <textpath xlink:href="#p1" startOffset="25%">31.1%</textpath>
    </text>
   </g>

   <g class="section">
    <path id="p2" d="M 250 250 L 458.7056796681 334.06508950971 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 171.59428106039 460.89699674856 Z" fill="#aa2200" />
    <text class="khs" x="250" y="240" font-size="30px" fill="#DDD">
     <textpath xlink:href="#p2" startOffset="18%">6.49 KH/s</textpath>
    </text>
    <text class="prc" x="250" y="280" font-size="15px" fill="#888">
     <textpath xlink:href="#p2" startOffset="18%">24.6%</textpath>
    </text>
   </g>

   <g class="section">
    <path id="p3" d="M 250 250 L 171.59428106039 460.89699674856 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 56.284491015906 364.45218031577 Z" fill="#eb2f06" />
    <text class="khs" x="250" y="240" font-size="40px" fill="#DDD">2.86 KH/s</text>
    <text class="prc" x="250" y="280" font-size="20px" fill="#444">10.8%</text>
   </g>

   <g class="section">
    <path id="p4" d="M 250 250 L 56.284491015906 364.45218031577 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 26.24340850501 226.37823540579 Z" fill="#c23616" />
    <text class="khs" x="250" y="240" font-size="40px" fill="#DDD">2.68 KH/s</text>
    <text class="prc" x="250" y="280" font-size="20px" fill="#444">10.2%</text>
   </g>

   <g class="section">
    <path id="p5" d="M 250 250 L 26.24340850501 226.37823540579 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 71.089441212269 113.55949298591 Z" fill="#e67e22" />
    <text class="khs" x="250" y="240" font-size="40px" fill="#DDD">2.30 KH/s</text>
    <text class="prc" x="250" y="280" font-size="20px" fill="#444">8.63%</text>
   </g>

   <g class="section">
    <path id="p6" d="M 250 250 L 71.089441212269 113.55949298591 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 163.8235888855 42.15720804554 Z" fill="#ffc500" />
    <text class="khs" x="250" y="240" font-size="40px" fill="#DDD">2.21 KH/s</text>
    <text class="prc" x="250" y="280" font-size="20px" fill="#444">8.38%</text>
   </g>

   <g class="section">
    <path id="p7" d="M 250 250 L 163.8235888855 42.15720804554 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 249.97751533812 25.000001123467 Z" fill="#f39c12" />
    <text x="250" y="240" font-size="20px" fill="#DDD">1.65 KH/s</text>
    <text x="250" y="280" font-size="10px" fill="#444">6.25% KH/s</text>
   </g>

   <g class="section">
    <path id="p8" d="M 250 250 L 249.97751533812 25.000001123467 A 225 225, 0, 0, 1, 250.01678524623 25.000000626099 Z" fill="#425a62" />
    <text x="250" y="240" font-size="15px" fill="#FFF">0.42 H/s</text>
    <text x="250" y="280" font-size="10px" fill="#444">0.00%</text>
   </g>

   <g class="center section">
    <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="123.75" stroke="black" fill="black" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="1" />
    <text x="250" y="250" font-size="40px" fill="#DDD">26.41 KH/s</text>
    <text x="250" y="280" font-size="20px" fill="#444">$99.58 USD</text>
   </g>
  </g>
 </svg>
</main>




I would like the center text to change to show the details of each sector as the sector is hovered over... that is why there are multiple cirlces.  The other circles were to mask the text from other sectors... because I couldn't get the CSS to work quite right.

See haolt's answer it looks spot on.
